# Does height of table changes with more content in rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 tables.
Table 1 contains 5 rows and 2 columns.Each row is populated with field name and data.
Table 2 also contains 5 rows and 2 columns But just field name and value  "NULL".

When i look both tables in browser,Both are different regarding height.
Table 1 is much more longer than table 2.This mean the height of both tables are different.

But when i try to find out height of tables using Jquery,Height is same. :(
Does this mean that if tables has same no of rows then there height is same?

Both tables have class name .specstabel

Using this function for finding height of both tables with class name specstabel.

```
function getHeight(group) {

    group.each(function() {

        var thisHeight = JqueryAlias(this).outerHeight();
        alert(thisHeight);

    });

}
```

and how i am calling this function.
getHeight(JqueryAlias(".specstabel"));

I don't know why height is same for both tables even they are different in height in browser.?

Here is the HTML of table 1.

```
<table width="95%" border="1" class="specstabel">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" bgcolor="#254061" colspan="2"><strong>Phone Specifications</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>Name</label></td>
      <td align="left">abcddsfdsfsdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>Class</label></td>
      <td align="left">8th Grade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>School Name</label></td>
      <td align="left">school1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="40" align="left"><label>Teacher Comments</label></td>
      <td height="50" align="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rutrum urna et odio sodales lobortis. Donec iaculis magna sed urna scelerisque finibus. Suspendisse mattis magna vel laoreet mattis. Proin vel dignissim elit. Maecenas nisl eros, consequat dignissim tincidunt condimentum, sollicitudin eu ipsum. Proin eleifend finibus velit eget commodo. Nam metus enim, tincidunt nec ullamcorper non, porttitor a lectus. Curabitur tincidunt eu felis vitae</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML of table 2.

```
<table width="95%" border="1" class="specstabel">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" bgcolor="#254061" colspan="2"><strong>Phone Specifications</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>Name</label></td>
      <td align="left">abcddsfdsfsdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>Class</label></td>
      <td align="left">8th Grade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="22" align="left"><label>School Name</label></td>
      <td align="left">school1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="40" align="left"><label>Teacher Comments</label></td>
      <td height="50" align="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Please put Your HTML code.

Comment: Post a complete code example so we can see the issue please.

Comment: Please check the html of both tables.Table 1 height is more because it contains more data in the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call

```
 getHeight(jQueryAlias('.specstabel'));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes here is a demo of table height](http://jsfiddle.net/7py660zo/1/) being affected by new table rows;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#demoTable tbody').append('<tr><td>ColA</td><td>ColB</td></tr>');
        $('#height').html( $('#demoTable').outerHeight() );
    });
});
```

If you're able to post a JSFiddle example of your code then SOers will find it much easier to help.